# Where is fast and simple Views for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, TextView is extremely heavy and functional, but in most cases we need only "LabelView" : one line, ellipsize and alignment. We don't need html,multiline etc.

Do exist third-party libraries with lightweight views?

Comment: What is slowing you down about a TextView? You could create your own, `extend View`

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Comment: You've already asked this today

Comment: Lightweight Label is popular usecase for TextView , in most examples (from google etc)we have this usage. But if use TextView for render changeable text textview turn on internal DynamicLayout and method TextView.onMeasure consumes ~30% cpu usage (in my case). Why doesn't exist simple Label in SDK? Or open-source realization? Is it connected with some problems? The only way i see is to create custom view based on Canvas.drawText

Comment: See this https://engineering.instagram.com/improving-comment-rendering-on-android-a77d5db3d82e

Answer (score 5):

> TextView is extremely heavy

You are welcome to your opinion.

> Do exist third-party libraries with lightweight views?

Nothing that is lighter weight in rendering text than `TextView`.

> method TextView.onMeasure consumes ~30% cpu usage (in my case)

That is a meaningless statistic, as anybody with rudimentary knowledge of arithmetic should recognize. What  matters is the actual **time** consumed by methods like `onMeasure()`, which is on the order of microseconds.

> Why doesn't exist simple Label in SDK?

It is called `TextView`.

> The only way i see is to create custom view based on Canvas.drawText

Which is pretty much what `TextView` does. After all, you will need to do most of the same measurement logic in your `onMeasure()` that `TextView` does.

That being said, you are welcome to create your own `LabelView` that does things how you want.

Comment: i hope its okay to laugh :D